# Boostrap Datepicker Default Date Highlight

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I am currently using bootstrap datepicker and I believe by default the current date should be highlighted once the user opens the datepicker. As of the moment, there is no date highlighted when you open the datepicker for the first time. Please see attached photo.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this code:

```
$('#datePicker').datepicker({
todayHighlight: true
});
```

where `#datePicker` is your field id replace with your field id.

Answer (score 1):

By default this option is disabled. See the option [todayHighlight](https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.org/en/release/options.html?highlight=default#todayhighlight)